# Get focused View from ViewPager

Tags: android, view, pager, android-viewpager, viewpage

i use the ViewPager for switching views with left/right swipe.

The ViewPager needs an Adapter, so I've built this one:

```
public class ListViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

protected static final String TAG = "ListViewPagerAdapter";
protected static final int NUM_VIEWS = 3;

protected final Activity mActivity;

public ListViewPagerAdapter(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_VIEWS;
}

@Override
public void startUpdate(View container) {}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
    // ViewPager
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;

    // Wird verwendet, um die Views aufzurufen
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = mActivity.getLayoutInflater();

    // Standardmäßig ist news eingeblendet
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_fragment, null);
    // Falls sich die Position verändert, so verändert sich auch die View
    if (position == 0) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.favorite_fragment, null);
    } else if (position == 2) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.videos_fragment, null);
    }

    // View einblenden
    viewPager.addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    // ViewPager
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) container;
    // View
    View view = (View) object;

    // View löschen
    viewPager.removeView(view);
}

@Override
public void finishUpdate(View container) {}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    View _view = (View) object;
    return view == _view;
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {}
 }
```

Now, i want to get the current focused view by the viewpager.
I tried getChildAt(x), but it does not work.

Are there some example, or do you have any idea how to get the current view?

Thanks

Answer (score 89):

It is possible to save the currently active object (View, Fragment, ...) by overriding [PagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#setPrimaryItem%28android.view.ViewGroup,%20int,%20java.lang.Object%29) method. For example:

```
private View mCurrentView;

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    mCurrentView = (View)object;
}
```

Comment: it is a shame getting current visible item implementation is not built-in at pager adapters. brilliant answer, thank you.

Comment: perfect, that was what i also looking for... this is really wierd!! big thanks for that!

Comment: Note: this method is called multiple times on page swipe

Comment: it seems that method is Deprecated.

Comment: @osayilgan, it's not deprecated.
The deprecated function is this other one:
`setPrimaryItem (View container, int position, Object object)`

Comment: @DanieleB Yes, you are right, didn't pay that much attention. Thanks.

Comment: This works! But still so annoying it's a necessary work around.

Answer (score 41):

You have to register a listener to your `ViewPager` :

```java
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new MyPageChangeListener());
```

You have to customize the listener by extending a stub listener:

```java
private int focusedPage = 0;
private class MyPageChangeListener extends ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        focusedPage = position;
    }
}
```

I found this by looking at the ViewPager.java source code in the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html). I read that we can do more, for example catch `onPageScrollStateChanged`.

To build the adapter, I used the code [on this blog post](http://geekyouup.blogspot.com/2011/07/viewpager-example-from-paug.html). You might want to have a look.

Comment: I see how that gets you the current position but I'm not clear on how you can get the current view from that.

Comment: Please be aware that if you are using a ViewPagerIndicator in combination with the ViewPager, the listener must be set on the indicator, not on the pager.

Comment: @JoeRegan I was able to get the current view from `getChildAt(int)` on the `ViewPager`, giving it the last known position that I got from the `OnPageChangeListener`.

Comment: Yuriy's comment is perfectly right: if you want to use this solution with more than 3 views in your pager, you need to call setOffscreenPageLimit on your pager and pass it the number of views

Answer (score 41):

You can add a tag to the created view in the instantiateItem method:

```
view.setTag(position);
```

Later you can access the current selected view by:

```
mPager.findViewWithTag(mPager.getCurrentItem());
```

Comment: I think this is a easiest way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, but you should save the original tag and restore it afterwards.

Comment: The `view` is the object which will be return like `return view`.

Answer (score 4):

I recently needed to implement this exact solution. Here's the way I did it:

```
Map<Integer, Object> views = Maps.newHashMap();

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, int position) {
  /* Create and add your View here */
  Object result = ???

  views.put(position, result);
  return result;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
  /** Remove your View here */

  views.remove(position);
}

protected View findViewForPosition(int position) {
  Object object = views.get(position);
  if (object != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
      View view = getChildAt(i);
      if (isViewFromObject(view, object)) {
        return view;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: This works for me, thanks! But in your `findViewForPosition(int)` method, why iterate through the children and call `isViewFromObject(View,Object)`? I've implemented this method simply as `return views.get(position);` and haven't yet had any problems.

Comment: Because there is no guarantees that the children are added to the container in any particular order. Also the PagerAdapter API allows for an arbitrary object reference to be returned, this isn't necessarily a View. I made a mistake in my sample, the Map should be Map<Integer, Object>

Comment: still, this wont give u the current displayed or focussed view, as in the above function I will need to pass a position and that is value is quite hard to get i.e. the current positioned view, if i could have got the position, i cud have directly used the getChildAt(x) rather then this..getCurrentItem() returns the index from data set.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public View getCurrentView(ViewPager pager) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pager.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = pager.getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getX() <= pager.getScrollX() + pager.getWidth() && 
            child.getX() + child.getWidth() >= pager.getScrollX() + pager.getWidth()) {
            return child;
         }
     }
     return getChildAt(0);
}
```

Comment: Not really. Works fine for few views. Fails for views when I Scroll back.

Comment: @user1938357: this is because the adapter removes the views to free memory.

Answer (score 1):

To get focused view I use this way:

When I inflate my view before add it on ViewPager I set tag to it. Then I check this tag.

```
private View getCurrentView()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < pager.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        View v = pager.getChildAt(i);
        if (v != null)
        {
            if (v.getTag().equals(pageList.get(pager.getCurrentItem()).getTag())) return v;
            // pageList is a list of pages that I pass to page adapter
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: what is the tag value that u r matching here? secondly where do u set the tag value in pageList? as If i tried setting it intantiateItem method but again that is based upon the view position not the acutal data object index in the pageList?

Answer (score 0):

the given answers were not really suitable for me, they all have unwanted side effects. Either I have to add unnecessary variables (I like clean code) or I have to work around the Android framework itself.

My solution is based on reflection, which accesses the array list of all objects within the ViewPager and returns the current selected object in the ViewPager. It has almost no side effects (reflection is slow, subclassing of an existing class) and it keeps the code clean.

```
public class ViewPagerEx extends ViewPager {

    private static final String TAG = ViewPagerEx.class.getSimpleName();

    public ViewPagerEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ViewPagerEx(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Object getCurrentObject() {
        try {
            final Field itemsField = ViewPager.class.getDeclaredField("mItems");
            itemsField.setAccessible(true);

            final ArrayList<Object> items = (ArrayList<Object>) itemsField.get(this);

            final int currentItemIndex = getCurrentItem();
            if (currentItemIndex < 0 || currentItemIndex >= items.size()) {
                return null;
            }

            final Object infoItem = items.get(getCurrentItem());

            final Class<?> itemInfoClass = findItemInfoClass(ViewPager.class.getDeclaredClasses());

            final Field objectField = itemInfoClass.getDeclaredField("object");
            objectField.setAccessible(true);
            return objectField.get(infoItem);

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }

    private Class<?> findItemInfoClass(final Class<?>[] classes) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
            if (classes[i].getSimpleName().equals("ItemInfo")) {
                return classes[i];
            }
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot find class ItemInfo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
    private View mCurrentView;

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        Fragment f = (Fragment) object;
        mCurrentView = f.getView();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.i("maylonsales", "onPageSelected position " + position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

If you examine carefully, there are at most 3 views saved by ViewPager.
You can easily get the current view by

```
view     = MyActivity.mViewPager.getChildAt(1);
```

Comment: I've noticed it has up to 4 views saved by ViewPager, its only 3 when your looking at the first or last view in the pager.

Comment: Ahh, this is because I have a title strip. Regardless, its 2 views in the pager when viewing the first and last

Answer (score -1):

Am I missing something? There's only ever 3 children inside the ViewGroup, so it boils down to:

```
int current = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
int childCount = viewPager.getChildCount();
// If there's a single page or we're at the beginning, return the first view
if (childCount == 1 || current == 0) {
  return viewPager.getChildAt(0);
} else { //For any other case, we want the second child. This is either the last page or the page in the middle for any other case.
  return viewPager.getChildAt(1);
}
```

Comment: If there is only ever three items (unless you use setOffscreenPageLimit to expand this), viewPager.getChildAt(1) will only ever current the middle item as the last item will have an index of 2.