# When should a Fragment's onActivityCreated be called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a few Fragments in a ViewPager, and I've found the Fragment's `onActivityCreated` and `onCreateView` are both being called on the page before I expect.

For example, when the ViewPager transitions from page 2 to 3, then the Fragment at page 4's `onCreateView` and `onActivityCreated` are being called.

I'm intending to initiate a network request in `onActivityCreated` but it is starting one screen too soon. According to the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)), `onActivityCreated` is called "when the fragment's activity has been created and this fragment's view hierarchy instantiated." which leads me to believe I'm using the method correctly.

Comment: In a ViewPager, the neighboring views are loaded to be smoother loading. That's why they are called early

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26400014/how-to-handle-network-calls-inside-a-fragment might help.try a demo @ https://github.com/shomeser/view-pager-fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ViewPager loads the next fragment for smooth transition between fragments, and that's why your next fragment's `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` and `onResume()` is getting called.
So, add `onPageChangeListener` on your viewPager like:

```
yourViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener{
    @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        switch(position){
            //your code for network operation
        }
    }
    @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}

});
```

Comment: Thanks. I am glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 5):

For smooth loading of data view pager will load the fragments in advance.
1. If you are at 1st position(first fragment),so its automatically loads the next 2 fragments
2.Or if you are at 2 or later,then it will load previous one fragment and next fragment

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this is done for smooth loading of data in a view pager. What you can do though is call your code in `onAattach()` or when your fragment is visible to the user in `onStart()`. [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) gives more details on lifecycle methods.