# How to render SQLite table data in a fragment of tabbed activity using List view

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, nullpointerexception

I am trying to display the table data from SQLite database onto the activity_main.XML. Everything went well. When I am trying to display the same table data onto a fragment of a tabbed activity, I am getting the errors.

I am new to the SQLite database and tabbed activity.

The three fragments are named fragment_one.xml,fragment_two.xml,fragment_three.xml.

I want the SQLite data to be displayed in fragment_two.XML.

The GitHub link for the source code is given below

https://github.com/Nithin543/Team_5_Project/tree/master/Source/app/src/main/java/com/example/cyclone/cyclone_1

Could you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: post the error log! and the code which is generating the error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

It happens because FragmentPagerAdapter loads next/previous fragment in memory for smoother transition and that's why before coming to the foreground your fragment's `onCreate()`, `onCreateView()` and `onResume()` is called.
Try in your activity:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch(position){
                    //Do your fragment specific task here
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

You can check my answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428662/when-should-a-fragments-onactivitycreated-be-called/38428898#38428898](http://here)