# How to display only cache memory images in ViewPager using Universal Image Loader Android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, universal-image-loader

I want to display only those images that were loaded into cache memory once we downloaded from url using `Universal Image Loader`

***Example***

I have **15 URLS** to download image and display in`ViewPager`, but out of them only 5 were downloaded and i closed the app.. Now i don't have any internet connection to get all the other images from web, but app will show only 5 images and remaining pages will be blank..

Is is possible to get the list of only those images from `cache Memory`??

How can we restrict `ViewPager` from other blank pages?

I have successfully implemented `Universal Image Loader`, but got stuck on these issues.

Any idea/suggestion/sample would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: @NOSTRA, Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define whether image was cached on disc using disc cache:

```
File cachedImage = imageLoader.getDiscCache().get(imageUrl);
if (cachedImage.exists()) {
    /// image is cached
}
```

You can check every image URL, define which images are cached and configure ViewPager appropriately.

Comment: How to set wallpaper using ViewPager? I am unable to get view of pager to set in bitmap @NOSTRA

Comment: This is completely other question. And I don't know the answer for wallpapers. About ViewPager - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8638772/913762