# How do I get the child View of a ViewPager at a given item

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'll keep the question as short and simple as humanly possible.

```
View activeView = mViewPager.getChildAt(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
```

returns the child view when the current item is 0 and 1. But if the current item is 2 it returns `null` . Why is that?

*edit: Let me rephrase myself. How do I get the child View of a ViewPager at any given item position?*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It turns out `getChildAt(int)` was not the right approach. What I did was retrieve the Adapter used in the ViewPager and found my views from there:

```
adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

View activeView = fragment.getView();
```

As already noted the viewPager will only contain the current child and adjacent children(currentItem() +/- 1) unless otherwise specified through `setOffscreenPageLimit()`

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone coming in now, getItem is no longer a method on a pagerAdapter

Comment: @Ronnie Troj i m getting null in activeView  why

Comment: Receiving an Illegal State Exception with this code: "Fragment MyFragment not attached to Activity".

Comment: @Erum call adapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, mViewPager.getCurrentItem()); instead of getItem

Answer (score 7):

Your view pager adapter is holding maximum of 2 pages, i.e 2 views/fragments, the rest of them are recycled. In other case, what you did not mentioned is that you might have 2 pages/views in the ViewPager.

Please look at `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()`

Answer (score 3):

Add tag to Viewpager return view.

Below link will help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20186828/1271891

Comment: nice one. Looks exactly for this to populate the view dynamically. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

During my endeavors to find a way to decorate android views I think I defined alternative solution for th OP's problem that I have documented in [my blog](http://bstrandjev.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/the-missing-viewpager-getcurrentview.html). I am linking to it as the code seems to be a little bit too much for including everything here.

The solution I propose:

- keeps the adapter and the view entirely separated
- one can easily query for a view with any index form the view pager and he will be returned either `null` if this view is currently not loaded or the corresponding view.

(This question is very simple to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854783/android-viewpager-get-the-current-view/27251590) in which I have posted [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27251590/1108032)).

Answer (score -1):

How many child views should the be?

Also a ViewPager doesn't have all childs loaded at the same time. Only the one it is showing and the next one. You can use `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit()` to, for example 3 or 4, to 'preload' more items into the viewpager.