# Viewpager inside a DialogFragment - wrong dialog height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to use a viewpager inside a dialog fragment (a SherlockDialogFragment actually). Every page consists of a text view with a left drawable. The problem i am facing is that the dialog size is 'wrong'. The width is too little, the height too much (it extends from top to bottom). For the width, i have "solved" this problem forcing its minimum width to be 70% of the screen width (via code, in the onCreateView() method of the dialog fragment). For the height, i don't know how to fix it. **There is a button down there, but it can't be seen**:

[image]

The viewpager is working (i can swipe the three pages i have setup). This is the dialog fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dlg_bkg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="TITLE"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icon"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/lineseparator"
        android:visibility="visible" />



    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/welcome_dlg_pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/lineseparator"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

     >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/close_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackground"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:text="Close"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the example page layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/welcome_dlg_page1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Page 1 - ekrjgwoirhfwiorht2iu3hr2984hr893rhg3hff2jif283hr29837rh283eh23r23r2r23rwrgioehrg803"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/img1"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Why the dialog height is too much? How can i fix it?

Comment: It's due to android:background="@drawable/dlg_bkg". Try removing this and check again.

Comment: It is a small ninepatch png. Can't be.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue. I also wanted the height as per the viewpager's current item so I followed the following steps.

First of all, You need to override the `onMeasure` method of the viewpager. as explained [here](https://mobikul.com/viewpager/).

```
public class WrapContentViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public WrapContentViewPager(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }

    public WrapContentViewPager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);           
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        View child = getChildAt(getCurrentItem());
        if (child != null) {
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    }
}
```

After that, Add PageChangeListener so that we can remeasure the viewpager's height every time when the viewpager item has been changed. We will add a `initPageChangeListener()` method and call it in the constructor.

```
public WrapContentViewPager(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
    initPageChangeListener();
}

public WrapContentViewPager(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initPageChangeListener();
}

private void initPageChangeListener() {
    addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            requestLayout();
        }
    });
}
```

Now, I had the issue when the viewpager adapter has more than 3 items, So I added following lines in `onMeasure()`. as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16512532/3342570).

```
if (getAdapter() != null)
        setOffscreenPageLimit(getAdapter().getCount());
```

And, everything works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first part i.e., creating custom view pager alone worked fine for me. But the animation when we show the fragment is not good. It is adjusting the height from top to center.

Answer (score 0):

you have to overide the onstart method and set the height and width if dialouge fragment their,like

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
   super.onStart();

  if (getDialog() == null)
    return;

  int dialogWidth = ... // assign width here
  int dialogHeight = ... // assign height here

   getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);

}
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but while the windows will be of the desired width and height, the viewpager will still have the wrong height (and the button will be not visible).

Answer (score 0):

Answer here:

[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394681/android-i-am-unable-to-have-viewpager-wrap-content)

Extend the ViewPager class and override the onMeasure() method.