# ScreenSlideActivity not working

Tags: android

I need some help! I've downloaded the example for screen slide from http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#views and it worked fine, the thing is that when i try to add it to my project I cant make it work...
Ive added `android-support-v13.jar` as a referenced library and all errors disappeared, but when i launch the activity for the screenslide I have these errors:

```
04-23 13:03:02.671: W/dalvikvm(2820): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/ccc/ScreenSlideActivity$ScreenSlidePagerAdapter; (151)
04-23 13:03:02.671: W/dalvikvm(2820): Link of class 'Lcom/example/cccc/ScreenSlideActivity$ScreenSlidePagerAdapter;' failed
04-23 13:03:02.671: E/dalvikvm(2820): Could not find class 'com.example.ccc.ScreenSlideActivity$ScreenSlidePagerAdapter', referenced from method com.example.ccc.ScreenSlideActivity.onCreate
04-23 13:03:02.681: W/dalvikvm(2820): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1074 (Lcom/example/ccc/ScreenSlideActivity$ScreenSlidePagerAdapter;) in Lcom/example/ccc/ScreenSlideActivity;
```

I know it has something to do with `FragmentManager` not finding its constructor, I have tried importing the `support.v4 FragmentManager` but it didint work:

[Error: The constructor MainActivity.ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950833/error-the-constructor-mainactivity-screenslidepageradapterfragmentmanager-is)

[need help to fix code for getting current view in viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383065/need-help-to-fix-code-for-getting-current-view-in-viewpager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could solve it!
I removed `android-support-v13.jar` and corrected all the imports:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

And the most important was this one:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
```

Because that was the only import that originally was v13 from the example from http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html.
These changes were made in `ScreenSlidePageFragment` and `ScreenSlidePagerActivity`.
I could reach the solution thanks to the linked posts.